# What is the proper procedure to deploy a JavaFX applet/weblauncher without triggering countless security threats?

Tags: java, security, intellij-idea, applet, javafx

I have a very simple JavaFX application. Small time, academic stuff. I'd like to place a weblaunch/jnlp link on my blog so that my professors can open it.
Helpfully javafx has all the deploying infrastructure ready, so I can easily create the .jar the .jnlp file and the .html using javascript to open javafx.

The problem is java security. Java security stops the .jnlp/applet from running. This is particularly annoying because if you donwload and double-click the jar it all works perfectly.
**What should I do to avoid java-security to block the application?**

I have done two things, to little avail.
In the ant-build I added:

```
     <manifest>
        <attribute name="Permissions" value="sandbox"/>
    </manifest>
```

With this, if I also set my java-security to medium (the minimum) I can run the jnlp after wading through countless warning dialogs. Obviously I can't ask my professors to go through this.

I also created a keystore to sign my stuff, which in ant looks like this (this is also helpfully generated by intellij):

```
<signjar alias="${artifact.sign.alias.MacroIIDiscrete}" keystore="${artifact.sign.keystore.MacroIIDiscrete}" storepass="${artifact.sign.storepass.MacroIIDiscrete}" keypass="${artifact.sign.keypass.MacroIIDiscrete}">
  <fileset dir="${artifact.temp.output.MacroIIDiscrete}/deploy">
    <include name="*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</signjar>
```

And what's really weird is that when I sign all the jars, security stops the .jnlp from loading even at medium security. It's actually worse! (running the main jar straight still works).
The console shows this error:

> ```
> java.lang.SecurityException: JAR manifest requested to run in sandbox only:
> ```

while the dialog shows

> Application blocked by security settings

This is incredibly frustrating. I can't believe it is so hard just to let somebody run a sandboxed program. Is there something obvious I am missing?

Comment: Just to belabor the point, all the examples of javafx applets here http://www.jfxia.com/JFXDemos/ are all blocked by security. What's the point of Java-guis at this point?

Comment: *"**What should I do to avoid java-security to block the application?**"*   Jump into your time machine and travel back to that more innocent time when applets were not seen as in inherent threat to security. *"I can't believe it is so hard"*  I can't believe you're so naiive.  Applets were never simple, and have just (with the recent security updates) become an order of magnitude more difficult.